# Android Studio's Translations Editor doesn't load - stuck on "Loading string resource data" loading indicator

Tags: android, android-studio, localization, translation

When I try to open the Translation Editor it gets stuck on "Loading string resource data" and I get an IDE error. This used to work fine a few weeks ago until adding in the `en-001` and `es-419` locales. I tried a new project and Translation editor did open fine until I added those specific locales. I'll include the IDE error logs below.

[image: Screenshot of stuck on "Loading string resource data"]

[image: IDE error dialog]

[image: string.xml files in my project]

IDE logs:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 001
at com.android.ide.common.resources.LocaleManager.getRegionName(LocaleManager.java:60)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.Locale$3.compare(Locale.java:241)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.Locale$3.compare(Locale.java:230)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.Locale$1.compare(Locale.java:199)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.Locale$1.compare(Locale.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:296)
at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:221)
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1750)
at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:392)
at java.base/java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1$2.end(DistinctOps.java:168)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
at com.android.tools.idea.editors.strings.StringResourceData.getLocaleList(StringResourceData.java:253)
at com.android.tools.idea.editors.strings.table.StringResourceTableModel.<init>(StringResourceTableModel.java:62)
at com.android.tools.idea.editors.strings.ResourceLoadingTask.onSuccess(ResourceLoadingTask.java:64)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.finishTask(CoreProgressManager.java:615)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.finishTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:162)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$6(CoreProgressManager.java:538)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:214)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$200(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:196)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:794)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:350)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:84)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:133)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:46)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:189)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:885)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:754)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:441)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:825)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:440)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:794)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:486)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported a bug with Google IssueTracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239923746

A workaround for now is to rename the `values-b+en+001` directory to `values-b+en+GB` then change it back to it's original name when you're done with the translations editor. If you use `values-b+es+419` you'll need to change that to `values-b+es+ES` temporarily too.